# Float to integer conversion for control program crashes arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, reset, pid

I have a program which estimates battery capacity, range as well as runs different control loops on an arduino MEGA2560 to control an eBike. I was using floating points which gave me quite a slow sampling frequency (10Hz). I now changed this to use integers by multiplying everything by at least 1000 so I can still keep a 3 decimal accuracy. However, as soon as the Arduino leaves setup and starts running loop, it crashes and restarts. I have a doubt that this could be due to the fact that my program takes too much RAM. How could I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
    #include <EEPROM.h>
    #include <memorysaver.h>
    //#include <TFT_HX8357.h> // Hardware-specific library
    #include <URTouch.h>
    #include <URTouchCD.h>
    #include <memorysaver.h>
    #include <UTFT.h>


    //TFT_HX8357 myGLCD = TFT_HX8357();       // Invoke custom library#include <TFT_HX8357.h> // Hardware-specific library
    //
    //TFT_HX8357 myGLCD = TFT_HX8357();       // Invoke custom library

    UTFT myGLCD(ILI9481,38,39,40,41);
    URTouch myTouch(6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

    int  buttonst, horn=5, throttle=8, powermode=1, alarmsystem=1, xtouch, ytouch, k1=0, k2=0,modechange,ncycles, p=9, divider=12, addresstd=0, kpow[3]={0,0,0}, kcur[3]={25,0,0}, ksp[3]={0,0,0};
    long pushed, pushedt, timesp, timespm1, powtimesm, factor, powtimesp, start, elapsed, powtime, powresttime, shuntvoltage, batvoltage, current, power, consumah, capacstore, consumwh, consumbatper, consumbatrange, distance, distanceint, throttlein, throttleout, distancedisp, Totaldist, velocity, Totaldistcheck;
    long throttlesmooth, capaccheck, capacactual,consumahstore, errorpower[2], errorpoweri, errorpowerli, errorcuri, errorcurrent[2], errorpowerl[2], diff, errorspeed[2], errorisp, outspeed, outcurrentctl, outspeedctl, elapsedtot, errorsmooth[2];
    float internresistance=0.00112;

    long batteryspec[6][56]={{4200,4000,3940,3900,3876,3860,3852,3844,3826,3809,3795,3783,3765,3744,3728,3710,3692,3672,3650,3631,3613,3591,3573,3556,3532,3508,3488,3463,3439,3417,3399,3380,3366,3352,3332,3312,3291,3273,3253,3237,3217,3196,3176,3150,3123,3087,3051,2994,2929,2868,2796,2727,2650,5261,2502},//5A discharge 18650GA SPEC
      {1,2,15,47,85,133,186,244,309,383,447,506,554,612,681,735,793,852,921,1007,1081,1150,1236,1300,1358,1438,1518,1587,1667,1747,1822,1888,1955,2014,2072,2152,2232,2317,2389,2466,2524,2594,2658,2722,2786,2847,2925,2983,3063,3133,3186,3245,3293,3330,3357,3368},
      {4200,4020,3980,3945,3927,3914,3904,3890,3874,3860,3843,3821,3797,3776,3756,3734,3713,3695,3675,3652,3634,3614,3593,3569,3543,3522,3500,3480,3459,3441,3419,3398,3378,3360,3339,3321,3301,3278,3254,3230,3199,3164,3128,3085,3037,2990,2937,2878,2837,2795,2746,2693,2648,2598,2549,2496},
      {0,7,33,84,151,223,294,377,457,521,574,646,718,785,851,931,1011,1091,1171,1251,1323,1397,1469,1547,1632,1701,1778,1853,1928,1994,2088,2175,2258,2333,2413,2487,2562,2634,2706,2775,2842,2908,2697,3023,3074,3116,3159,3205,3234,3261,3287,3314,3333,3352,3365,3379},//3A discharge 18650GA SPEC
      {4200,4131,4094,4073,4054,4038,4028,4015,4003,3985,3965,3945,3921,3894,3870,3850,3830,3811,3795,3775,3759,3739,3716,3692,3674,3648,3623,3601,3578,3561,3542,3522,3502,3486,3467,3445,3423,3401,3374,3350,3324,3291,3253,3210,3168,3123,3075,3026,2964,2897,2838,2781,2715,2652,2585,2502},
      {0,0,36,84,154,223,289,356,420,489,553,620,686,761,838,908,985,1054,1134,1214,1283,1358,1438,1523,1584,1667,1755,1835,1920,2002,2085,2170,2255,2327,2402,2482,2567,2644,2724,2791,2850,2908,2964,3015,3058,3095,3132,3167,3207,3245,3271,3295,3320,3336,3354,3365}}; //1A discharge 18650GA SPEC

    long cyclicspec[2][44]={{0,894,7151,16090,26400,37500,50950,61680,74190,85360,96540,107260,118880,130950,142120,154640,168040,182350,194860,208270,219890,234200,246700,262800,276200,291400,303900,317300,3271500,341500,354000,364000,374500,383460,395080,405800,418300,431700,444000,455900,468800,481900,491600,499700},
      {3441,3435,3342,3292,3235,3178,3121,3078,3014,2957,2921,2892,2842,2792,2750,2721,2679,2643,2607,2564,2543,2507,2479,2436,2407,2379,2357,2336,2336,2336,2336,2336,2336,2321,2300,2279,2271,2243,2229,2214,2193,2179,2164,2157}};

    extern uint8_t BigFont[];
    extern uint8_t SevenSegNumFont[];

    void EEPROMWritelong(int address, long value)
          {
          //Decomposition from a long to 4 bytes by using bitshift.
          //One = Most significant -> Four = Least significant byte
          byte four = (value & 0xFF);
          byte three = ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
          byte two = ((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
          byte one = ((value >> 24) & 0xFF);

          //Write the 4 bytes into the eeprom memory.
          EEPROM.write(address, four);
          EEPROM.write(address + 1, three);
          EEPROM.write(address + 2, two);
          EEPROM.write(address + 3, one);
          }

    long EEPROMReadlong(int address)
          {
          //Read the 4 bytes from the eeprom memory.
          long four = EEPROM.read(address);
          long three = EEPROM.read(address + 1);
          long two = EEPROM.read(address + 2);
          long one = EEPROM.read(address + 3);

          //Return the recomposed long by using bitshift.
          return ((four << 0) & 0xFF) + ((three << 8) & 0xFFFF) + ((two << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) + ((one << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
          }

    long pidcurrent_control() {

  long dt, outcurrent=0, outpower=0;
     int i=0, descurrent, despower;
     i++;
     dt=millis()-powtime;
     powtime = millis();
     if (powermode==1) { //Furo default mode
      if (current>40000) {
        descurrent=40000;
        errorcurrent[1]=descurrent-current;
        if (i>=2) {
          //Integrate the error
        errorcuri+=errorcurrent[1]*dt;

        outcurrent=(kcur[0]*errorcurrent[1]+kcur[1]*errorcuri+kcur[2]*((errorcurrent[1]-errorcurrent[0])/dt));
        }
        errorcurrent[0]=errorcurrent[1];
        return outcurrent;
        }  
        if (((batvoltage*current)/1000)>2000000) {
         despower=2000000;
          errorpower[1]=despower-batvoltage*current/1000;
          if (i>=2) {
        //Integrate the error
        errorpoweri+=errorpower[1]*dt;
        outpower=kpow[0]*errorpower[1]+kpow[1]*errorpoweri+kpow[2]*((errorpower[1]-errorpower[0])/dt);
        }
        errorpower[0]=errorpower[1];
        return outpower;
        } 
        }
      else { //Eco mode
       despower=550000;
       errorpowerl[1]=despower-batvoltage*current/1000;
          if (i>=2) {
          //Integrate the error
          errorpowerli+=errorpowerl[1]*dt;
          outpower=kpow[0]*errorpowerl[1]+kpow[1]*errorpowerli+kpow[2]*((errorpowerl[1]-errorpowerl[0])/dt);
        }
        errorpowerl[0]=errorpowerl[1];
        return outpower;
        }  
        }

    void cyclescaling() {
    int j=1;
     if (ncycles<=499000) {
     while ((ncycles<cyclicspec[0][j-1])||(ncycles>cyclicspec[0][j])){    
               j++;
        }
        factor=(cyclicspec[1][j-1]+(ncycles-cyclicspec[0][j-1])*(cyclicspec[1][j]-cyclicspec[1][j-1])/(cyclicspec[0][j]-cyclicspec[0][j-1]))/cyclicspec[1][0];
    }
    else {
        factor=(cyclicspec[1][41]+(ncycles-cyclicspec[0][41])*(cyclicspec[1][42]-cyclicspec[1][41])/(cyclicspec[0][42]-cyclicspec[0][41]))/cyclicspec[1][0];
    }
    }

    long pidspeed_control() {
    int isp, dtsp;
    isp++;
    dtsp=millis()-powtimesp;
    powtimesp = millis();
    errorspeed[1]=46000-velocity;
    if (isp>=2) {
        errorisp+=errorspeed[1]*dtsp;  
        outspeed=(ksp[0]*errorspeed[1]+ksp[1]*errorisp+ksp[2]*((errorspeed[1]-errorspeed[0])/dtsp));
        }
        errorspeed[0]=errorspeed[1];
        return outspeed;
    }



    void throttlesmoothing() {
     int i=0, dtsm;
     i++;
    long currentmap=map(throttlein,800,3600,0,40000);
     dtsm=millis()-powtimesm;
     powtimesm = millis();
     errorsmooth[1]=currentmap-current;
          if (i>=2) {
          //Integrate the error
          throttlesmooth=kcur[0]*errorsmooth[1];//+kcur[2]*((errorsmooth[1]-errorsmooth[0])/dtsm);
        }
        errorsmooth[0]=errorsmooth[1];
    }

    void SOC() {
      int currentref=current/p, compbat=batvoltage/14;
      int j=1,l=1;
      long stateofc1=0, stateofc2=0;

      if (currentref<=1000){
        while (((compbat)>batteryspec[0][j-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[0][j])){    
               j++;
        }
        capacactual=(batteryspec[1][55]-(batteryspec[1][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[0][j-1])*(batteryspec[1][j]-batteryspec[1][j-1])/(batteryspec[0][j]-batteryspec[0][j-1])))*p;
        Serial.println("\n");
        Serial.println(current);
            Serial.println(batvoltage);
                Serial.println(batteryspec[1][j-1]);
      }

     if ((currentref>1000)&&(currentref<=3000)){
        while (((compbat)>batteryspec[0][j-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[0][j])){    
               j++;
        }
        stateofc1=(batteryspec[1][55]-(batteryspec[1][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[0][j-1])*(batteryspec[1][j]-batteryspec[1][j-1])/(batteryspec[0][j]-batteryspec[0][j-1])))*p;

         while (((compbat)>batteryspec[2][l-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[2][l])){    
               l++;
        }
        stateofc2=(batteryspec[3][55]-(batteryspec[3][l-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[2][l-1])*(batteryspec[3][l]-batteryspec[3][l-1])/(batteryspec[2][l]-batteryspec[2][l-1])))*p;
        capacactual=stateofc1+(currentref-1)*(stateofc2-stateofc1)/(3000-1000);
      }

       if ((currentref>3000)&&(currentref<=5000)){
        while (((compbat)>batteryspec[2][j-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[2][j])){    
               j++;
        }
    //    stateofc1=(batteryspec[3][55]-(batteryspec[3][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[2][j-1])*(batteryspec[3][j]-batteryspec[3][j-1])/(batteryspec[2][j]-batteryspec[2][j-1])))*p;

         while (((compbat)>batteryspec[2][l-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[2][l])){    
               l++;
        }
    //    stateofc2=(batteryspec[3][55]-(batteryspec[3][l-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[2][l-1])*(batteryspec[3][l]-batteryspec[3][l-1])/(batteryspec[2][l]-batteryspec[2][l-1])))*p;
        capacactual=(batteryspec[3][55]-(batteryspec[3][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[2][j-1])*(batteryspec[3][j]-batteryspec[3][j-1])/(batteryspec[2][j]-batteryspec[2][j-1])))*p+(currentref-1)*((batteryspec[5][55]-(batteryspec[5][l-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[4][l-1])*(batteryspec[5][l]-batteryspec[5][l-1])/(batteryspec[4][l]-batteryspec[4][l-1])))*p-(batteryspec[3][55]-(batteryspec[3][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[2][j-1])*(batteryspec[3][j]-batteryspec[3][j-1])/(batteryspec[2][j]-batteryspec[2][j-1])))*p)/(5000-3000);

      }


    if (currentref>5000) {
       while (((compbat)>batteryspec[4][j-1])||((compbat)<batteryspec[4][j])){    
               j++;
        }
        capacactual=(batteryspec[5][55]-(batteryspec[5][j-1]+(compbat-batteryspec[4][j-1])*(batteryspec[5][j]-batteryspec[5][j-1])/(batteryspec[4][j]-batteryspec[4][j-1])))*p;
    }

    }


    void autonomy() {

      if (modechange==1) {
       consumah=0;
      }

        power=batvoltage*current/1000;
        SOC();

        if (capacactual!=capaccheck) {
          capaccheck=(capacactual+capaccheck)/2;
        }

      if (abs(capacactual-capacstore)>=100){   
         EEPROMWritelong(8,roundf(capacactual));
         capacstore=capacactual;
      }

      consumah += 1000*current*elapsed/1000/3600;
      capaccheck -= 1000*current*elapsed/1000/3600;
      consumwh += 1000*current*elapsed/1000/3600*batvoltage;
      elapsedtot += elapsed;
      consumbatper = (capaccheck)/(batteryspec[1][55]*p)*100;
      if (distance==0) {
        switch (powermode) {
          case 1: consumbatrange=45*batvoltage*capaccheck/980;
          break;
          case 2: consumbatrange=35*batvoltage*capaccheck/550;
          break;
        }

      } else {
      consumbatrange = distance/consumah*(capaccheck);
      }
      myGLCD.printNumI(consumbatrange/1000, 2, 350,275);
      myGLCD.printNumI(power/1000, 2, 350,205);
      myGLCD.printNumI(current/1000, 1, 30,50);
      myGLCD.printNumI(ncycles/1000, 1, 30,50+16*2);
      myGLCD.printNumI(consumbatper,1,350,50);
      myGLCD.printNumI(batvoltage/1000,1,350,50+16*2);

      return 0;

    }

    void speedometer() {
    int sense=digitalRead(46);
    long sensecst=691150*3;//x1 000 000

    if (sense==LOW) {
       timesp=millis()-timespm1;
       timespm1 = millis();
       velocity=3600/1000*sensecst/(timesp);//m/h
       if (timesp>1000) {
           velocity=0;
       }
    } else {
      if ((millis()-timespm1)>2000) {
        velocity=0;
      }
    }
    }



  void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      start=millis();
     // pinMode(43, OUTPUT);//Speedo power
     // pinMode(46, INPUT);//Speedometer
      pinMode(A2, INPUT);//Throttle in
      pinMode(A7, INPUT);//Battery voltage
      pinMode(A4, INPUT);//Shunt
      pinMode(throttle, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(47, INPUT);
      analogWrite(10,255);
      analogWrite(11,255);

      myGLCD.InitLCD(LANDSCAPE);
      myTouch.InitTouch(LANDSCAPE);
      myGLCD.fillScr(0,0,0);
      myGLCD.setColor(VGA_WHITE);
      myGLCD.setBackColor(0,0,0);
      myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);
      myGLCD.print("FURO SYSTEMS",(480-16*12)/2,16);
      myGLCD.print("WELCOME",(480-16*7)/2,(320-16)/2);
      myGLCD.setDisplayPage(0);
      delay(2000);
      myGLCD.clrScr();
      myGLCD.print("FURO SYSTEMS",(480-16*12)/2,16);
      myGLCD.fillRoundRect((480-3*16-8)/2,320-16*2-4,(480-3*16-8)/2+3*16+6,228);
      myGLCD.print("ECO", (480-3*16)/2, 320-16*5);
      EEPROMWritelong(4,1000);
      ncycles=EEPROMReadlong(4);
      cyclescaling();

      for (int m=1; m<=5;m+=2) {
      for (int n=0; n<=55;n++) {
        batteryspec[m][n]*=factor;
        }
      }


      current=analogRead(A4);
      current=current/internresistance*5*1000/1023/75;

      batvoltage=analogRead(A7);
      batvoltage=batvoltage*5*1000*divider/1023;

      SOC();
      capaccheck=capacactual;
      capacstore=EEPROMReadlong(8);

      if (capacactual>capacstore) {
      ncycles+=1000;
      EEPROMWritelong(4,ncycles);
      EEPROMWritelong(8,roundf(capacactual));
      }

      if (capacactual<500) {
        powermode=2;
        myGLCD.fillRoundRect((480-4*16-8)/2,320-16*2-4,(480-4*16-8)/2+4*16+6,228);
        myGLCD.print("FURO", (480-4*16)/2, 320-16*5);
      }//3.21V per cell
      EEPROMReadlong(addresstd);
      Totaldist=EEPROMReadlong(addresstd);
      Totaldistcheck=Totaldist;
      digitalWrite(43,HIGH);
    }

    void loop() {
       throttlein=analogRead(A2);
       throttlein=throttlein*5*1000/1023;
       //throttlesmoothing();
       throttleout=throttlein/1000*255/5;
       analogWrite(8,throttleout);


       modechange=0;
        if (digitalRead(47)==LOW)
        { 
          if (buttonst==1) {
          pushed = millis();
          }
          buttonst=0;

          if ((millis()-pushed)>=2000)
          {
           distancedisp=0;
          }
          }

         if (digitalRead(47)==HIGH) {
          if (buttonst==0) {
            modechange=1;
            pushedt=millis()-pushed;
            if (pushedt<1900){
           if (powermode==1) 
          { powermode=2;
           myGLCD.clrScr();
           myGLCD.print("FURO SYSTEMS",(480-16*12)/2,16);
           myGLCD.fillRoundRect((480-4*16-8)/2,320-16*2-4,(480-4*16-8)/2+4*16+6,228);
           myGLCD.print("FURO", (480-4*16)/2, 320-16*5);
          }
          else  
          { 
            powermode=1;
            myGLCD.clrScr();
            myGLCD.print("FURO SYSTEMS",(480-16*12)/2,16);
            myGLCD.fillRoundRect((480-3*16-8)/2,320-16*2-4,(480-3*16-8)/2+3*16+6,228);
            myGLCD.print("ECO", (480-3*16)/2, 320-16*5);
          }
          }
          }
          buttonst=1;
         }


    batvoltage=analogRead(A7);
    batvoltage=batvoltage*5*divider*1000/1023;
    //speedometer();
    current=analogRead(A4);
    current=current/internresistance*5*1000/1023/75;
    elapsed = millis() - start;
    start = millis();

    if (modechange==1) {
       distance=0;
    }
    distanceint = (velocity/3600*elapsed/1000);//m
    distance += distanceint;
    distancedisp += distanceint;
    Totaldist += distanceint;

    if (abs(Totaldist-Totaldistcheck)>=100) { //later do it upon switch off
      EEPROMWritelong(addresstd,round(Totaldist));
      Totaldistcheck=Totaldist;
    }

    autonomy();

    if (velocity>45000) {
    outspeedctl=pidspeed_control();
    outcurrentctl=pidcurrent_control();
    long throttleout1=min(outspeedctl,outcurrentctl);
    throttleout=min(throttleout1,throttlesmooth);
    //analogWrite(throttle, map(throttleout, 0,5,0,255));
    } else{
    outcurrentctl=pidcurrent_control();
    throttleout=min(throttlesmooth,outcurrentctl);
    //analogWrite(throttle, map(throttleout, 0,5,0,255));
    }

    myGLCD.setFont(SevenSegNumFont);
    myGLCD.printNumI(velocity, (480-32*3)/2, (320-50)/2);
    myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);
    myGLCD.printNumF(distancedisp, 1, 30,175);
    myGLCD.printNumI(Totaldist, 30,175+2*16);

    }
```

Comment: emmm, you should maybe jut READ the battery value and not guest it...

Comment: Your program does nothing: save for the #includes, everything is inside a big comment that starts on line 10 with `/*`. Please edit the question and post your _actual_ code.

Comment: That is a lot of code to look at. Not sure anyone will. So some helpful pointers instead. Break down your code (into many functions?).   Start by calling only a few bits of it, then add more until the problem occurs.  Also, at this complexity, it might be worth it to abandon the Arduino paradigm and use real Atmel debugging hardware / software so that you can single step through your code.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Sorry about that just edited it.

Comment: Actually just solved it, it was a mistake with the UTFT library! Using printnumI instead of printNumF

Comment: Please write your own anwser and set this question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved this issue and noticed a few things for those interested: the printNumI() function was making the arduino crash as it was badly initiated with an extra argument. Once I solved this and replaced all my printNumF with printNumI I noticed a significant increase in sample rate of about 3-4ms per line changed. In addition, going from float to int calculation didn't change much as the TFT screen takes enormous amounts of computing power: takes me from 333Hz of sampling frequency to about 10Hz with the screen.